# Conditional formatting formula only partially including selected date ranges

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I implemented the formula below to apply formatting to a cell when today's date is 0-30 days from the date value in column G.It is working for the most part except it is not factoring in row 27 (highlighted row). I am unsure why. Does anyone see anything that stands out?

[image]enter image description here

[image]
[image]

UPDATE: Adding img:

[image]

Comment: Can you update your first screenshot to include column H?

Comment: @EngineerToast I added the new pic in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the formulas in column G are dependent on the values in column J. This explain why only row 25 has a `#VALUE!` error. However, your conditional formatting is based on column H. You only notice the issue in row 27 because that's the only row that has a date within 30 days in column J but not in column H. I would suggest one of two options:

- Change the conditional formatting to be based on column J
- Change the conditional formatting to be based directly on the values in column G (i.e., don't do date math, just check if the value in G is between 0 and 30)

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thank you! I went with option two. I over complicated it.